# Kafka and zookeeper docker containers talking to my api on the host machine

Tags: java, docker, apache-kafka

Step 1: Setting up Zookeeper and Kafka Containers

I've diligently followed the instructions outlined in a particular guide to establish a Zookeeper container, establishing a seamless connection with a Kafka container. This connection facilitates their communication through local ports. Furthermore, I've successfully created a topic named "foo," featuring a single partition. To populate this topic, I've dispatched a total of 42 messages using an appropriate Docker command. I've comprehended that a Kafka port is now accessible on my local operating system via "localhost:29092." This port essentially serves as a gateway for both message production and consumption.

Commands used to launch the Zookeeper container:

```
docker run -d --net=host --name=zookeeper -e ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT=32181 confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:4.0.0
```

Commands used to initiate the Kafka container:

```
docker run -d --net=host --name=kafka -e KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=localhost:32181 -e KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://localhost:29092 -e KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR=1 confluentinc/cp-kafka:4.0.0
```

Step 2: Integrating Kafka Producer and Consumer Scripts in Spring Boot API

Moving forward, my objective revolves around integrating Kafka producer and consumer scripts into my Spring Boot API. Remarkably, I'm striving to accomplish this without resorting to Docker Compose. My intention is to verify whether these two containers can function akin to a conventional Kafka distribution when operating on my host operating system.

Commands employed for launching the Kafka container:

```
public class KafkaProducer {private static final String TOPIC = "foo";...}
public class KafkaConsumer { @KafkaListener(topics = "foo", groupId = "group1")...}

spring.kafka.producer.bootstrap-servers: localhost:29092
spring.kafka.consumer.bootstrap-servers: localhost:29092
```

as result, I'm getting these ERRORS:

```
2020-12-23 14:38:45.937  WARN 14056 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-group1-1, groupId=group1] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:29092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2020-12-23 14:38:45.937  WARN 14056 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-group1-1, groupId=group1] Bootstrap broker localhost:29092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected.
```

What went wrong?

Comment: How are you starting the Kafka containers?  Can you run Kafka directly on the host, so you have one fewer totally new technology to work with?  (In particular there's a confusing bit where the initial Kafka connection has the server tell the client where to connect, and that can be tricky to get right in a mixed Docker/non-Docker environment.)

Comment: @DavidMaze
to run zookeeper container:
 `docker run -d --net=host --name=zookeeper -e ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT=32181 confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:4.0.0`  
  to run kafka container: `docker run -d --net=host --name=kafka -e KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=localhost:32181 -e KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://localhost:29092 -e KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR=1 confluentinc/cp-kafka:4.0.0`
 yeah, it does work perfectly with kafka_2.13-2.6.0 folder on my host. I know it's a confusing structure and my api should run in a third container, but I'm trying to understand how real Kafka container is.

Comment: What do you mean "how real"? 1)You don't need to use `--net=host`, and that only works as expected on Linux, anyway 2) Please read https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-listeners-explained/ 3) Using Compose would be easier (see the blog post) 4) why do you want/need to use an old version of Confluent Platform?

Comment: @OneCricketeer 
I have no experience with virtual os at all. It's kinda black box for me and I'd like to see how it does work step by step. 
1) and 4) I've copied from docs.confluent.io . 2 and 3 - ok

Comment: 4) You could read the warning at the top of the page that links to the current version ;)

Comment: In any case, the key takeaway would be that you need an advertised listener from the container that exposes and returns the Kafka address. With that information, you can either run the spring app in or out of a container, but you'd have to use different addresses and ports depending on how you configured Kafka

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, it works with a new version of the guide.

https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/quickstart/ce-docker-quickstart.html